# jQuery Countdown plugin not accepting time as well as date

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [jQuery Countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) but having some trouble getting it to show the right countdown.

I want to countdown to a date *and* a time, but everytime I add the time to the Date string, it stops working.

This works:

```
var openTime = new Date('2009,09,25');
$('#countdown').countdown({until: openTime});
```

But this doesn't:

```
var openTime = new Date('2009,09,25,08,00');
$('#countdown').countdown({until: openTime});
```

All I get is NaN's instead of numbers.  Am I passing in the time wrong? Or is there another way I should pass in the date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should pass it in either as a date string like this:

```
var date = new Date ( 'January 1, 2009 12:15:10' );
```

or as a comma delimited list of parameters, like this:

```
var date = new Date ( 2009, 0, 1, 12, 15, 0 );
```

In your example you're mixing both approaches.

Comment: Thank you - you have no idea how much time I spent looking for that today!!  Works like a charm!